# UI-Router + Kendo UI Grid, weird issue

Tags: angular-ui-router, kendo-grid

Ok so lemme explain first for those who are not familiar
Rule number for using Telerik's Kendo UI is to reference the following in this order Jquery.min.js>Angular.min.js>Kendo.all.min.js

Here is the pseudo-code of my web application

```
in my parent.html: 
-reference for jquery
-reference for angular 
-reference for kendo
-ui-view container

this is my ui-view(child.html)
-initialize kendo grid
```

What happened is that the kendo widget was not rendered
Then I looked at the console of the browser and there was something like
"Jquery should be initialized first before angular when using Kendo-UI widgets"

I tried removing the ui-view and and just yolo-pasted the contents of the child.html and the grid widget successfully  rendered

But when I use angular-ui-routing, the error appears again saying I should reference jquery first before referencing angular when using kendo widgets

Comment: how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can only load jQuery once.  I had a similar problem where I was calling it once from a shared view and once inside the main view.  You have child views?  My solution was to push the loading of the Javascript from the shared view to the main view, and also called them inside of the kendo tabStrips, because apparently those were sandboxed enough not to affect the main view.  The second loading of jQuery is what's crushing the kendo rendering; figuring out the workaround depends on the relationships between the views.